# Trying to install AMD proprietary drivers

Tags: drivers

I have downloaded the proper driver from the web but every time I try to open, it says not responding or will open in `gedit`, take forever to load, then say there was an error.

In the driver file it's marked as run as program. Am i missing something?

I believe I figured it out. .run has to be run through terminal. I tried installing from the terminal and got the following results:

```
=====================================================================
 AMD Catalyst(TM) Proprietary Driver Installer/Packager 
=====================================================================
Detected configuration:
Architecture: x86_64 (64-bit)
X Server: X.Org 6.9 or later 64-bit
loki_setup: directory: (null)
Installing package for: Ubuntu/trusty
fglrx_14.501-0ubuntu_.deb
fglrx-amdcccle_14.501-0ubuntu_.deb
fglrx-dev_14.501-0ubuntu_.deb
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-core.
dpkg: regarding fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb containing fglrx-core:
 fglrx-core conflicts with libopencl1
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 provides libopencl1 and is present and installed.
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:amd64 provides libopencl1 and is present and installed.

dpkg: error processing archive fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--install):
 conflicting packages - not installing fglrx-core
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx.
(Reading database ... 246099 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack fglrx_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx (2:14.501-0ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fglrx-amdcccle.
Preparing to unpack fglrx-amdcccle_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (2:14.501-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx:
 fglrx depends on fglrx-core; however:
  Package fglrx-core is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx-amdcccle:
 fglrx-amdcccle depends on fglrx; however:
  Package fglrx is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package fglrx-amdcccle (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.1+14.04.20140409-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 fglrx
 fglrx-amdcccle
fglrx-core_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb fglrx_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb fglrx-amdcccle_14.501-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
Cleaning up removed packages
Unable to open /etc/ati/control, please reinstall the driver.
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
fglrx_14.501-0ubuntu_.deb
fglrx-amdcccle_14.501-0ubuntu_.deb
fglrx-dev_14.501-0ubuntu_.deb
Removing temporary directory: fglrx-install.6hTiyp
```

Comment: I will follow this in detail tonight. I haven't come across this tutorial yet.

Comment: So that tutorial doesn't really say much. It says download the driver and install and thats the problem i'm running in is that it won't install it. It opens gedit then freezes and occasionally very slowly installs until it errors.

Comment: I believe i figured it out. .run has to be run through terminal?

Comment: Well i tried installing and go the following (put in answer as too much text)

Answer (score 3):

Solved - So apparently there is a OS package error or something in 14.04? I followed the whopping three commands halfway through this page (below) and everything seems to be working fine.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2266268&page=4

Commands from above link:

`sudo apt-get install libcheese*`

`sudo apt-get install xorg-video-abi-15`

`sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`